# How can I create a thread that can process all captured video frames in the background?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function that iterates over a video and extracts each frame as a CVPixelBuffer.

Each frame is displayed on the View without issue.

I'd like to send each frame to a separate thread/dispatch queue to do some image processing in the background whilst not interfering with the playback of the video.

Currently my DispatchQueue architecture is as follows:

Custom concurrent dispatch queue that grabs each frame from video
Once the frame is grabbed it is sent to the main queue for display
I then created another thread from within the first custom thread that is suppose to process the images.

The problem I have is that this thread seems to be dependent on the playback speed of each frame.  So if I playback the video at the nominal rate or even faster for some reason not all the frames get processed or even sent to the background queue. The video displays fine at 2x the nominal frame rate. However, to get each frame processed in the the separate queue I have to slow down the playback rate to almost 1/2 speed.

Here is the code:

```
 func processFrames () {


        let workingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "workingQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)
        let detectQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "detectQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)



        var index = 0

        workingQueue.async {

            while self.start {

                //Get frame as a CVPixelBuffer

                guard let pixelBuffer = self.videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: self.playerItem.currentTime(), itemTimeForDisplay: nil)
                    else {
                        return
                    }

                // Display frame to screen

                self.display(pixelBuffer)

                //Process images in different thread - Index and currentTime used to check if each frame is being processed

                detectQueue.async {
                    self.sceneDetector(pixelBuffer, time: self.playerItem.currentTime(), index: index)
                }

                //playback frame rate in denominator
                usleep(useconds_t(1000000/40))


                // Advance video 1 step
                self.playerItem.step(byCount: 1)
                index += 1


            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that your processing takes longer than the time of one frame? If so, the processing queue will be flooded over time and can't keep up. Consider not passing every frame to processing if possible.

Comment: Also, potential bug: when you call `self.playerItem.currentTime()` inside the processing queue, the player item might already have been advanced by the player queue, so `currentTime` is not the time of the `pixelBuffer`. You can get the current time outside the `async` call and pass it to the block directly to avoid this.